# Why do people disappear?

Tags: angel-beats

Why do people disappear if they become Angel's friend? Also, why did Otonashi say "we will not disappear, be our friend" (something like that)?

Why did other Angel's "friends" disappear and Otonashi and others didn't?

("Angel" is Kanade)

Comment: finish the anime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't watched *Angel Beats!* for a while but I tried to do the best research I could.

At the ending of episode 13, it is heavily implied that Otonashi

> did pass on. He reincarnates and meets the reincarnated Kanade.

Regarding people disappearing,

> Yui thoroughly explains that they disappear when they have their wishes fulfilled. They are in "*purgatory*" because they were unable to experience a normal youth before dying.

However, *Angel Beats: Another Epilogue* could falsify this, depending on how you view it:

> Otonashi has become the new student council president and is helping the students pass on. With this (OVA?), two endings are presented: Otonashi remains in "*purgatory*" to wait for Kanade like The Programmer (as the reincarnation has not been described to be limited it is possible that he could wait for many hundreds of years for her) or is just an add-on to the original ending, where Otonashi does move on.

Comment: This got spoilers but the question didn't? Is there a guide somewhere to what to put in spoilers?

Comment: I assumed by reading ton.yeung's "finish the anime" comment, the question was posted in the middle of the series, and this answer might spoil viewers who haven't watched until the end. You're free to un-spoil anything, but I don't think anyone who has watched the main *Angel Beats!* series also know/have watched *Another Epilogue*, so personally, I feel it's better to hide it on the spoiler block.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that people arrive in Angel Beats because it is like a teens purgatory. They have baggage and believe the life they lived was unfair to them. They disappeared once they both accepted, released their baggage, and were ready to move on.

Yuri was paralyzed from the waist down and could never go out and do anything. She got the chance to experience life. Angel's heart was failing. She got Otonashi's but never got the chance to thank him, which was her main baggage.

As we do not know the speed of time in *Angel Beats*, personally, I think the time moves faster. I believe Angel was maybe on life support waiting for the heart or in having the transplant which is why she was there.

I believe that *Angel Beats: Another Epilogue* supports this because

> he won't move on without her and is waiting for her to arrive once more. Until she does, he helps those who arrive accept what has happened and move on. It even says in that episode, "I heard he is waiting for someone."